# Showing Specific Data in by using the key in Firebase

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm new to android development and firebase so this may be a simple question.

I want to develop an application that matches the name in the grandChild in the firebase and then get the data of the key around it but the problem is when I retrieve the data it get the value of all child node in the database.

[image]

Here's the code that I have done

```
private void searchText() {
    final String mSearch = searchBar.getText().toString();

    //return REQUIRED if the searchBar is in filled
    if (TextUtils.isEmpty(mSearch)) {
        searchBar.setError(REQUIRED);
        return;
    }


    ValueEventListener valueEventListener = mDatabase.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

            for (DataSnapshot child : dataSnapshot.getChildren()){


                for (DataSnapshot grandChild : child.getChildren()) {


                    //check if mSearch is equal any grandchild in the firebase'
                    if(grandChild.getValue().toString().equals(mSearch)){

                        TextView mText = findViewById(R.id.searchResult);
                        String string = child.getValue().toString();
                        String string2 = string.replace("{","");
                        String string3 = string2.replace("}","");
                        String string4 = string3.replace(",","\n");

                        //retrieve the data from firebase and show in TextView
                        mText.setText(string4);
                    }
                }

            }

        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });

    mDatabase.addValueEventListener(valueEventListener);
}
```

the **result** is

> { Message = "...",Priority = "..",name="...",time="..."}

but the **result that I want** is ***only name and priority***

> { Message = "..",name=".."}

Is there any way to specify the route of the data that is retrieved?

Comment: It was like I have to type the name on the edittext and it will compare with the grandChild ( in this case is “aa” ) if it equal to each other, I want my app to show only Message and Name on the textView

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can query through your grand child.
Suppose you want to search by **name** from your database. To do this, follow below code

```
        DatabaseReference databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Data");

        Query query = databaseReference.orderByChild("name")
             .startAt(mSearchText)
             .endAt(mSearchText+"\uf8ff");

        query.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

                    for (DataSnapshot data:dataSnapshot.getChildren()){

                         String name = data.child("name").getValue().toString();
                         String priority = data.child("Priority").getValue().toString();

                    }

                }

                @Override
                public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

                }
            });
```

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you first parse the JSON into an object and then utilise only the required parameters you need.
For parsing, you can use SimpleJSON library.

Answer (score 1):

To be able to retrieve the `name` and the `Message` you can do the following:

```
DatabaseReference databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Data");
databaseReference.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
@Override
public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
     if(dataSnapshot.child("name").getValue().toString().equals(mSearch)){
       String message = dataSnapshot.child("Message").getValue().toString();
        mText.setText(message);
         }
    }

@Override
public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
   }
});
```

In the above code, you will be able to retrieve the `name` and the `message`, and then check if the `name` is equal to the value that is written in the search bar. After that you can assign the `message` to a `TextView`

Comment: So I don’t have to do the for loop to get the data that I want right?

Comment: you do for loop if there is a node between your current node and the data that you want to get, example if you have "Data/id/name:aa". Here in this case you do a for loop, but in your database your children are immediately under "Data"